# Getting undefined in console.log while fetching posts from jsonplaceholder in next

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to fetch posts from **jsonplaceholder** and using the **getStaticProps** method .inside i send a **HTTP** request through **axios package** and try to get data but it always gives **undefined**

**here is the code:**

```
import { Fragment } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Main = ({data}) => {
  console.log(data);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <section className="main mt-3">
        <div className="container-lg">
          <div className="text-center">
            <h3>
              <span className="text-primary fw-bold display-5 ">Welcome</span>{" "}
              <span className="text-dark fw-bold display-5 ">Next</span>
            </h3>
            <p className="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </Fragment>
  );
};


export const getStaticProps = async () => {
    const {data} = await axios.get(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
    );
  
    return {
      props: {
        data
      },
    };
  };

export default Main;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also using same API while learning Next JS .. see solution below.

response from API is under `response.data`

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const response = await axios.get(
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
  );
  return { props: { posts: response.data } };
}
```

Comment: thanks i know , i already destructure the response.data like const{data}= await axios.get ......  its a short method to destructure objects ,,, the error was not this but other errors in parent components is now solved

Comment: oh yes.. correct .. you already destructure it ... that cool you find a fix